# Global Variables Angular 5-Typescript

Tags: angular, variables, scope, local

I have an application in which I try to store data based on user action.

More specifically, I have a table in the user interface in which there is a column with ckeckboxes.

Based on the checkbox of the table row chosen by the user I want to pull some columns to make some checks.

By using the following function I can, based on the chosen checkbox, to  display the information that I want.

```
OnPropertyStorage (event: Event): any {

    let checkboxes;

    checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      const checkbox = checkboxes[i];
      checkbox.onchange = function()   {
        const currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        const secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i + 1 ];
        const thirdColumn  = secondColumn.getElementsByTagName('td');


        console.log('Id:'       + thirdColumn[0].textContent);
        console.log('volume:  ' + thirdColumn[2].textContent);
        console.log('weight:  ' + thirdColumn[3].textContent);


    };

  }

 }
```

My problem is how can I return to a variable that lives outside this function, the sum of the selected values ​​of a column.

If there is any nice article about variables scope in angular would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not using `(change)` angular binding in template to detect checkbox change? That will solve your problem straightaway

Comment: I can either use (change) data binding or simple (click="do whatever") function at checkbox properties.Thank @planet_hunter anyway.